# ASP.NET MVC Mobile View has different view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

The following pages are the default page of my site: Dashboard.cshtml, Dashboard.Mobile.cshtml.
The user can switch from the standard to the mobile page using the ViewSwitcher from NuGet.

However, my mobile page has a different view model than the standard page.

For the moment, I patched it quickly by putting both view models in the same class and the action method looks like this :

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    return this.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice
        ? this.GetMobileDashboardViewModel()
        : this.GetDesktopDashboardViewModel();
}
```

I feel this will get me killed by my peer in a code review. Is there a more proper way of handling this scenario where a mobile and standard page have different view models?

Cheers,

Eric

Answer (score 0):

If they aren't the same logic they shouldn't have the same controller method. It is as simple as that. Generally with mobile you end up throwing some data away, and that is ok. So if you can just use the desktop viewmodel do so.

For something like a dashboard you might want to use partial views anyways, this way you only pull what you need and can have some flexiblity.